# How do you get any useful call stack information when debugging react native?

Tags: debugging, reactjs, react-native

When I try to debug react native, it usually looks like this.

```
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (ReactCompositeComponent.js:785)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:811)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._updateRenderedComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:735)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._performComponentUpdate (ReactCompositeComponent.js:715)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.updateComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:634)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.receiveComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:534)
at Object.receiveComponent (ReactReconciler.js:131)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._updateRenderedComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:737)
```

There are no useful information and if I use `debugger` command to see what initiated the 50-depth call stack, then it almost always comes down to the `onmessage` method in `debuggerWorker.js', and it's almost zero useful.
How do you really debug your react native app?

```
onmessage = function(message) {
  var object = message.data;

  var sendReply = function(result) {
    postMessage({replyID: object.id, result: result});
  };

  var handler = messageHandlers[object.method];
  if (handler) {
    // Special cased handlers
    handler(object, sendReply);
  } else {
    // Other methods get called on the bridge
    var returnValue = [[], [], [], 0];
    try {
      if (typeof __fbBatchedBridge === 'object') {
        returnValue = __fbBatchedBridge[object.method].apply(null, object.arguments);
      }
    } finally {
      sendReply(JSON.stringify(returnValue));
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

I tend to use the stack traces to figure out the general area where the error occurred and then use the web debugger to actually find out what when wrong.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#chrome-developer-tools

Its actually pretty nice, you can open all your js files in the sources tab of the chrome dev tools and then put debug points in and just step through your file and view your variables.